# JNI syntax in Android NDK

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Quick question about the JNI syntax in Android NDK

This is my function name in c++ code

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ogs_test_ogskcg_ogstranspose(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
```

And my log cat error msg

```
09-10 01:08:38.476: WARN/dalvikvm(278): No implementation found for native Logs/test/ogskcg;.ogstranspose ()V
```

Can you let me know is it the name prefix problem or something else

Comment: You need to `loadLibrary` the native library containing the `Java_ogs_test_ogskcg_ogstranspose` function before that will work. Did the `loadLibrary` fail for some reason?

Comment: Library loaded successfully...if (f.exists())
            {
             System.load(storage+"/Android/data/libogskcg.so");
            }
            Log.w(TAG, "Library loaded libogskcg.so");

Comment: Make sure your log statement is _inside_ the `if`, so that you know it's actually tried to load the library. :-)

Comment: Thanks...some how missed it...now the msg didn't show in the logcat...looks like some problem with library loading

Answer (score 0):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ogs_test_ogskcg_ogstranspose(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
```

Should not be (you missed a L):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Logs_test_ogskcg_ogstranspose(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this("**void Java_ogs_test_ogskcg_ogstranspose(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)**") decleration. and use extern keyword

```
extern "C"{
 void Java_ogs_test_ogskcg_ogstranspose(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
}
```